# How to validate nested object with joi-browser

Tags: reactjs, joi

I am trying to validate an object that has a another nested object but no luck so far. Context:

```
class ContactForm extends Component {
  state = {
    contact: {
      name: { firstName: "", lastName: "" },
      email: "",
      subject: "",
      message: ""
    },
    errors: {}
  };

  schema = {
    name: Joi.object({ firstName: Joi.string(), lastName: Joi.string() })
      .required()
      .label("Name"),
    email: Joi.string()
      .email()
      .required()
      .label("Email"),
    subject: Joi.string()
      .min(5)
      .max(50)
      .required()
      .label("Subject"),
    message: Joi.string()
      .min(5)
      .max(50)
      .required()
      .label("Message")
  };
}
```

I've tried reading the joi documentation but I couldn't find an example similar to my situation.The form looks like this by the way:

[image: form]

Notice that I added a label to the name object in my scheme, which is not showing in the error message as the other properties in my schema. Please let me know if you need more context than this to edit my post, I'm stuck here :/

Comment: You mean first name  validation is not working?

Comment: Well first and foremost I would like to know if I built my schema properly given the object that I'm trying to validate, basically I did guess work with the nested object "name". The error message should say "name" is not allowed to be empty, given that I added a label to the name object in my schema.